# Swap method results in disappearing points in Manim scene

Tags: animation, permutation, swap, manim

I am trying to make an animation where n points are equally distributed around a circle and an animation displays the permutations of those points by swapping their positions simultaeneously .

My issue is that when the animation ends  either one of the points disappears from the scene or two  distinct points get sent to the same position , here's the code :

```
from manim import*
import numpy as np
from itertools import*
import random

class CircleWithPoints(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        n = 6  # Number of points
        radius = 2
        colors = [RED, GREEN, GOLD, BLUE, PINK, PURPLE]

        # Create circle
        circle = Circle(radius=radius, color=WHITE)
        self.play(Create(circle))

        # Create points and assign colors
        points = []
        for i in range(n):
            angle = i * 2 * np.pi / n
            x = radius * np.cos(angle)
            y = radius * np.sin(angle)
            point = Dot(point=[x, y, 0], color=colors[i])
            points.append(point)
            self.play(Write((point)),run_animation=.25)

        all_permutations = list(permutations(range(n)))
        random_permutation =list(random.choice(all_permutations))
            # Permutation animation
        new_points=[]
        animated_new_points=[]
        animated_points=[]
        for i in range(n):
                next_index = random_permutation[i-1]
                next_point = points[next_index-1]
                if next_point is not points[i]:
                    animated_new_points.append(next_point)
                    animated_points.append(points[i])
        self.wait(1)
        
        self.play(*[Swap(animated_points[i],animated_new_points[i]) for i in range(len(animated_points))])

        self.wait(1)
```

I tried making a copy of the list of points to only take into account the points that are not fixed by the permutation  however it doesn't seem like it worked

Comment: I tried your code and it looked fine. Could you specify the issue maybe with an image or two? Also which version of manim do you use?